# How I get a div opacity effect if I have a mouseover

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, html, mouseover

I have a ASP.NET Application and I want a effect with divs. If I make a mouseover about a div a Want that this opacity is 0.9 and if I make a mousedown I want a opacity of 0.6. I use two divs. The one div is in the other div and in this I use Controls.

if My Mouse is not in the div:

[image]

If My Mouse is in the div:

[image]

My Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="lw_content" runat="server">
    <div class="createuser">

        <div class="create_box">
            <div class="newUser">

        Benutzer Anlegen <br/>
        <br/>
        <table>
            ...
        </table>

        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAnlegen" runat="server" Text="Benutzer anlegen" 
                    onclick="btnAnlegen_Click" />

             </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

My CSS:

```
div.createuser {

    background-image: url(../images/bg_createuser.jpg);

    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 450px;
    z-index: n;
}

div.create_box {

      width:400px;
  height:350px;
  margin:30px 100px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }

div.newUser {

    margin:30px 40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
    font-size: small;opacity:1.0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

I have in my div.createuser a image as Background with opacity 0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps

```
div.newUser {
   filter:alpha(opacity=50);
   opacity: 0.5;
}

div.newUser:hover {
   filter:alpha(opacity=90);
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: that is html5/css3 only. You should add the solution for older browsers as well. Also you need all vendor prefixes on filter to make it cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the opacity in background rgba color. it works at all browsers: i used black background to notice the opacity in your example. Also use this meta tag so it works at IE

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

div.newUser{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);    
}

 div.newUser:hover{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);    
}
```

or you can do it with opacity like that:

```
div.newUser{
opacity: 0.5;    
}
div.newUser:hover{
opacity:0.9;    
}
```